# In how many ways we can arrange $10$ objects $a_1, a_2, a_3,....,a_{10}$ in a line such that neither $a_1, a_2$ are together nor $a_3,a_4$.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In how many ways we can arrange $10$ objects $a_1, a_2, a_3,....,a_{10}$ in a line such that neither $a_1, a_2$ are together nor $a_3,a_4$.

**Approach $1$:**

Let $n(A)$ denotes when $a_1a_2$ are together.

$n(B)$ denotes when $a_3a_4$ are together.

$n(A\cap B)$ denotes when $a_1a_2$ as well as $a_2a_4$ are together.

$\implies n(A)=9!\cdot2!, \quad n(B)=9!\cdot 2!\quad n(A\cap B) =8!\cdot 2! \cdot 2! $

So by inclusion exclusion principle and De Morgan's law

$n(\bar{A}\cap \bar{B})=Total-n(A\cup B)$

$\implies 10!-(2\cdot 9!+2\cdot 9!-4\cdot8!)$

So I obtained result as $58\cdot8!$.

**Approach $2$**

Let first arrange $6$ boys $a_5,a_6,a_7,a_8,a_9,a_{10}$ then place $a_1, a_2$ in between $7$ their gap created by $a_5,a_6,a_7,a_8,a_9,a_{10}$ and arrange them in $2!$ ways

And now place $a_3, a_4$ in between $9$ gaps created by $a_1,a_2,a_5,a_6,a_7,a_8,a_9,a_{10}$ and arrange them in $2!$ ways.

So this can be done in $6!\cdot {7\choose 2}\cdot 2!\cdot {9\choose 2} \cdot 2!$

using this approach I am obtaining $54\cdot 8!$

**I don't know what I am missing in second approach and what is going wrong in second approach**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In approach $2$, you are leaving out any permutation where $(a_1,a_3,a_2)$ appears as a consecutive subsequence.

That is, in your first step where you place $a_1$ and $a_2$ in the gaps formed by $a_5,\dots,a_{10}$, it is actually OK to place $a_1$ and $a_2$ in the same gap, as long as you place either $a_3$ or $a_4$ in the gap between $a_1$ and $a_2$ in the second step.